# Parse JSON string to use in AJAX success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have code that generates a JSON string. An example string that is generated by that code is as follows. I have validated it through the JSON lint tool and it validates perfectly.

```
{"ShipToName" : "(    ) CARPINTERIA         CA", "ShipToAddress1" : "3785 SANTA CLAUS LANE", "ShipToAddress2" : "", "ShipToCity" : "CARPINTERIA", "ShipToState" : "CA", "ShipToZip" : "93013", "ShipVia" : "UPS", "Terms" : "01", "SalesRep" : "KV1" }
```

I then have some JQuery that is going to parse that string. Right now I am just trying to alert one of the parts of the string to be sure the code is working correctly. I have tried both of the following with no success:

Attempt #1: Alerts 'undefined'

```
function hidShipTo_IndexChanged(sender, args) {
                var strComboID = $find("<%=rcbCustomer.ClientID%>");
                var strValue = strComboID.get_value();
                var strShipToVal = $("#hidShipTo").val();
                var strData = "{ strSoldToSelected: '" + strValue + "', strShipToSelected: '" + strShipToVal + "' }";
                alert("yes");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/ProductServer.asmx/PopulateShipToDetails",
                    data: strData,
                    contentType: "application/json; character=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.SalesRep);
                    },
                    failure: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error1:" + xhr.status);
                        alert("Error2:" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Attempt #2: throws an error inside of a JQuery library object

```
function hidShipTo_IndexChanged(sender, args) {
                var strComboID = $find("<%=rcbCustomer.ClientID%>");
                var strValue = strComboID.get_value();
                var strShipToVal = $("#hidShipTo").val();
                var strData = "{ strSoldToSelected: '" + strValue + "', strShipToSelected: '" + strShipToVal + "' }";
                alert("yes");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/ProductServer.asmx/PopulateShipToDetails",
                    data: strData,
                    contentType: "application/json; character=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.SalesRep);
                    },
                    failure: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Error1:" + xhr.status);
                        alert("Error2:" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Any ideas on how I can access each of the items in the JSON String?

Thanks!

Comment: `success: function (msg) { console.log(msg);                     alert(msg.SalesRep);` Does it show what you expect?

Comment: So, the JSON string is inside `strShipToVal` variable? And you want to access the individual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your code does not throw an undefined exception, then we can deduce 'msg' is not undefined.

Use a debugger to see what your msg really contains:

```
alert(msg.SalesRep);
console.log(msg);
```

note: contentType should be 'charset=utf-8', not 'character=utf-8'. also the string you're sending is not valid json. It should be double quoted instead of using single quotes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that tip, but the problem is on the return of the already validated JSON string as listed in the question, not on the string being passed in.

Comment: Here is the string that goes into the console:

`d: "{"ShipToName" : "(0001) MIAMI               FL", "ShipToAddress1" : "PTY 7966", "ShipToAddress2" : "8610 NW 72ND STREET", "ShipToCity" : "MIAMI", "ShipToState" : "FL", "ShipToZip" : "33166", "ShipVia" : "SRG", "Terms" : "01", "SalesRep" : "999" }"`

Comment: You validated my answer, does that mean your problem is solved ? if so, you could edit your question or comment to explain what the problem really was.

Comment: @MichaelMahony nevermind me, didn't saw you answered already.

Comment: I marked you as the answer because your answer led me to what the problem was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was really simple once I checked the console log. I added this line of code and I was able to begin accessing everything in the JSON string:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense:

```
var strData = "{ strSoldToSelected: '" + strValue + "', strShipToSelected: '" + strShipToVal + "' }";
```

It should just be

```
var strData = { strSoldToSelected: strValue, strShipToSelected: strShipToVal };
```